# bash: set array env variable and de-referencing it from any shell script fails

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I set the a array as an environment variable in this manner
 eg. script `test.sh`

in test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
export STRING=( "str1" "str2" )
```

source test.sh

now in script `test-1.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ${STRING[0]}
```

the response is nothing, just a blank line,
  whereas, if I try to set `STRING="str1"` in test.sh
  and do `echo $STRING` in `test-1.sh`, this works.

tests are executed from root user only,
  Now how to set array as env variable , so that I can call the elements of array as per requirement? Earlier, I have tried to even modify `/etc/bashrc` and that also didn't result in anything positive.

I need to set the array as env variable as there may be many scripts that i have to write which shall use these variable settings.

can anybody provide me suggestions to correct me where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read the fine manual, "bugs" section.

> Array variables may not (yet) be exported.

Though, I don't know that many consider this an actual bug. Other shells that support ksh-style arrays don't allow exporting them either.

You may pass around array definitions rather easily, through parameters or variables or the environment. It isn't usually very useful though.

```
function f {
    unset -v "$2"
    typeset "$2"
    eval "${!1}"
    typeset -p "$2"
}

typeset -a a=(a b c)
myArr=$(typeset -p a) f myArr a
```

Answer (score 2):

The misunderstanding is in thinking that environment variables are only used by shells - they are not.  No attributes, including readonly, integer, and arrays, can be exported into the environment block.  Environment variables may be read by any language, C, C++, Perl, Java, Python, PHP, and so on.  They also exist on Windows.

So, how could another language support Bash specific attributes?  All environment variables are converted to strings, except in Bash where array values are not exported at all.

Korn shell will export just the first element.  ksh93 also does some `exec` exploitation to preserve variable attributes exported to Korn shell children.

By the way, it is considered bad practice to use UPPERCASE for variable names, since they could collide with those used by the shell.  Also, on Bash 3, the name STRING has issues when exported (fixed in Bash 4).

Answer (score 1):

The environment variables passed from processes to their children are unstructured strings; arrays cannot be supported.  You can demonstrate this in Bash:

```
export x=foo
printenv x
```

That outputs `foo`.  If I now cause `x` to become an array

```
x=(foo bar)
printenv x
```

We see no output (`x` is not exported).

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to put an array into an environment variable, and environment variables can only be strings. bash doesn't have a method for properly serializing/deserializing arrays; do so manually.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html) says passing array as env variable is possible with bash script though. It works for defining and dereferencing the array in bash command, but it does not work when dereferencing from bash script (ubuntu 18.04).