# assign array value to ENV var on .env file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, environment-variables

I need to set an array of strings on my .env file and cant find information about the right syntax. Test for this takes quite a while so I wanted to save some time. Some of this options should work:

```
MY_ARRAY=[first_string, second_string]
MY_ARRAY=[first_string second_string]
MY_ARRAY=['first_string', 'second_string']
```

Can someone tell me which?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I know dotenv does not allow setting anything except strings (and multiline strings). The parser syntax is:

```
LINE = /
  \A
  (?:export\s+)?    # optional export
  ([\w\.]+)         # key
  (?:\s*=\s*|:\s+?) # separator
  (                 # optional value begin
    '(?:\'|[^'])*'  #   single quoted value
    |               #   or
    "(?:\"|[^"])*"  #   double quoted value
    |               #   or
    [^#\n]+         #   unquoted value
  )?                # value end
  (?:\s*\#.*)?      # optional comment
  \z
/x
```

The reason behind this is shell and OS support for setting other [types of env variables is spotty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100409/bash-set-array-env-variable-and-de-referencing-it-from-any-shell-script-fails).

You could use a separator such as commas or pipes (|) and split the string with `ENV['FOO'].split('|')`. But maybe what you are trying to do should be solved with an initializer which combines ENV vars.

Comment: Im going with your advice of splitting the var using commas. thank's @max.

Comment: Great advice regarding combining ENV vars via initializers. This is a much less kludgy solution vs. splitting the var string.