# In php, environment arrays are not passed in

Tags: php, arrays, environment, getenv

If I declare an array in the shell environment, it does not appear in PHP.
A scalar works fine. E.g.:
Shell script:

```
declare -a TARGETS
TARGETS[0]="/etc" 
TARGETS[1]="/boot"
export TARGETS
export HOST="localhost"
```

PHP:

```
$TARGETS = array ();
$TARGETS = getenv ("TARGETS");
$HOST = getenv ("HOST");
```

$TARGETS will be empty and $HOST will contain "localhost".

phpinfo shows $HOST and its value in the Environment section. $TARGETS is absent from phpinfo output :/
I cannot find anything that says that environment arrays are not passed into PHP but is this actually the case or have I missed something obvious?
BTW, I also tried using $_ENV and $_SERVER with the same result.

This is not the same as [bash: set array env variable and de-referencing it from any shell script fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100409/bash-set-array-env-variable-and-de-referencing-it-from-any-shell-script-fails) as that was in 2012 when Bash did not support array variables. Now it does.

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100409/bash-set-array-env-variable-and-de-referencing-it-from-any-shell-script-fails

Comment: FYI, `$TARGETS` isn't empty, it's boolean `false`.

Comment: Yes - me being careless with terms :/