# Use Bash associative array in CMake

Tags: bash, cmake

I have the need to access a `bash` associative array element via `cmake`. So assume that my declaration and access was something like the following in bash:

```
~ declare -x someText=124
~ echo $someText
124
~ declare -A mymap=( [foo]=bar [baz]=quux)
~ echo ${mymap[foo]}
bar
```

Access in `CMakeLists.txt` would be:

```
message(STATUS "$ENV{someText})
message(STATUS "$ENV{mymap})
```

when I run cmake I get the following:

```
-- 124
--
```

So, the associative array cannot be accessed via the $ENV{} cmake command. Any ideas how to access it? To be specific, I don't care about the complete associative array, just one element in it.

Comment: The `bash -c ` opens a sub-shell, the array `mymap` defined in the first command won't be available in the second `echo`

Comment: ok, but even if I get rid of bash -c and I run every command by itself, I get the same message.

Comment: @Inian: `bash -c` opens a chid process, its not a sub-shell.  A sub-shell is where existing variables (and other resources) are copied to the child whether they are exported or not.  Since the parent (cmake) is not bash then it can't create a bash sub-shell.

Comment: @TassosTzavellas: you will, you cannot *import* a variable value from another process (a shell), let alone another language, without some sort of inter-process communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake cannot access *array* variables created in a bash shell.

Process `cmake` doesn't see an *array variable* - unlike to "normal" variable, *array* variable **isn't part of the environment** passed to the process.

Even another bash subprocess doesn't see array variable, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100409/bash-set-array-env-variable-and-de-referencing-it-from-any-shell-script-fails).